# JDBC Driver Jars Path for Seahorse Deepsense

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, etl

As per the documentation from `seahorse deepsense.ai`, Custom JDBC connectivity can be achieved in 2 ways.

- Adding the JDBC jar library to cluster deployment.
- Adding JDBC driver JAR file to Seahorse shared folder jars.

Can anyone share the exact path in seahorse for putting driver jars as i am getting the below error when connecting to `MySQL database.`

> Error while executing a node: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Please provide a link to the exact documentation you used, and describe exactly how and where you put the driver jar.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please find the link [seahorse deepsense](https://seahorse.deepsense.ai/reference/productionizing.html#custom-jdbc-drivers) and i have tried to put the driver jar in **/usr/share/seahorse** as well as **/usr/lib64/seahorse/** in my linux system.

Comment: Putting things in `/usr/share/seahorse` or `/usr/lib64/seahorse` does not match what is described in the documentation you link, please make sure you follow the instructions. Also, please read [Setting up JDBC Data Source with custom JDBC Drivers](https://seahorse.deepsense.ai/reference/data_sources.html#setting-up-jdbc-data-source-with-custom-jdbc-drivers) it says: _"This functionality requires placing adequate JDBC driver JAR file to Seahorse shared folder `jars`."_ Note, I know absolutely nothing about seahorse, but it looks like you're doing the wrong things.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : I am unable to find the shared folder `jars` in the seahorse path.